# Не могу выставить hw_mode=a на Raspbian

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Задача в том чтобы перекидывать на смартфоны по wifi файлы через adb.
Настроил для этого raspberry 3 b+ как роутер по этой [инструкции](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) и столкнулся с проблемой скорости передачи, для сравнения файлы по шнурку передаются за 1 \ 2 минуты, а по wifi за 4 \ 6 минут.

Можете подсказать, как я могу увеличить скорость передачи по wifi?

Смотрел в настройки hostapd.conf , подумал что проблема может быть в hw_mode, в нем я могу указать только g = IEEE 802.11g (2.4 GHz) и b = IEEE 802.11b (2.4 GHz). Но когда указываю a = IEEE 802.11a (5 GHz) ничего не работает (wifi raspberry просто не раздает, и само собой указываю только буквы "g, b или а").

Можете подсказать чего я не понимаю или в какую сторону копать? С подобным сталкиваюсь первый раз

Comment: Вам лучше обратиться с этим вопросом в англоязычное сообщество по Raspberry, там неплохая активность и больше шансов получить ответ на свой вопрос. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: wi-fi в 3 малинке сидит на usb, поэтому скорость будет всегда низкой.

Comment: Поменять на плату с x86 и сетевой картой на PCI(e)?

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, понял свою ошибку на счет hw_mode, нужно было просто поменять канал на 149 (соответствующий 5ггц). Время передачи заняло вместо 4-х минут 2 минуты, уже не плохо. Посмотрю еще в сообществе и на платы с "PCI(e)"

Comment: Появилась вторая проблема, не все смартфоны могут подключится к 5ггц wifi